# The type org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Compiling the following code yields this error:

> The type org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>   (this error is for last line of code)

I think I should add a .jar file in build path, but I don't know what is it?

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
context.addComponent("test-jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
```

Comment: spring jars. You need to check the version of spring framework needed and download it from here http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add [Spring Framework](http://springsource.org/spring-framework)'s

```
org.springframework.context-3.x.x.jar
```

to your project's build path. Depending on which third party library you're using it may have additional Spring dependencies and you would have to add those Spring jars too. You'd most likely need `org.springframework.core-3.x.x.jar` too.

Consult your direct dependencies' documentation to find out what its dependencies are.